# How do I reverse the effects of str() Method in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am wondering if python has an in-build method to reverse the str() method.

Example: MyList contains a dictionary, a string and an integer.

```
MyList = [{1: 'one'}, 'blarg', 964]
```

Let's say i want to arrange these items in order of size(length).
here is my function

```
def sort_by_length(mylist):
    newlist = []
    final = []
    for i in mylist:
        newlist.append(str(i))
    final = list(reversed(sorted(newlist, key=len)))
    for n,i in enumerate(final):
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            final[n]=int(i)
        else:
            pass
    return final
```

If I run this Function on MyList

```
sort_by_length(MyList)
```

The current output is:

```
["{1: 'one'}", 'blarg', 964]
```

Expected output:

```
[{'1': 'one'}, 'blarg', 964]
```

I was able to change the Integer back from a string but the dictionary remains a string in Quotation Marks(obviously because i only reversed the str() only for the Integers and not the dictionaries).

How would I be able to reverse this element back to a Dictionary?

Comment: By size do you really mean the length of their string representation, or are you after something like [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof).

Comment: You shouldn't cast your dict into a string. Keep it as it was. You should therefore rewrite the *key* function instead of using the `len` builtin.

Comment: And the short answer to "reversing `str()`" is: no.

Comment: How did you end up with such a different types in your list? Also is the number considered a length of 1 or 3?

Comment: Actually, the Answer from user3100115 did the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the  key parameter to `sorted` to specify a function to be called. Here a `lambda` expression will work fine.

```
>>> MyList = [{1: 'one'}, 'blarg', 964]
>>> sorted(MyList, key=lambda x: len(str(x)), reverse=True)
[{1: 'one'}, 'blarg', 964]
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally `str()` is not meant to give something that you can decode back into a python object. It is meant to give a human readable string. If you want to encode into a string that is machine readable use something like [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Another alternative is [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) and [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: @MagnusHoff The documentation on `repr()` reads as following: `For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval()` so while `repr` might work there are no guarantees and most of the time you are better off using something that is designed for that.